# Solve the following equation for $A,B,a_i,a_{i-1},\cdots,a_0 \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Find the integer values of $A,B,a_i,a_{i-1}\cdots a_1 \in \mathbb{N}$, so that the following equation is satisfied: $$a_i\cdot a_{i-1}\cdots a_1\cdot A^2+A(a_i^2\cdot a_{i-1}\cdots a_1 +a_i\cdot a_{i-1}^2\cdots a_1+\cdots+a_i\cdot a_{i-1}\cdots a_1^2+B\cdot a_i\cdot a_{i-1}\cdots a_1-n\cdot a_i\cdot a_{i-1}\cdots a_1)+n=0$$
>   where $i\in \mathbb{N}, i\geq 2$ is costant, as $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\leq2$.

So far I have obtained:
$$A^2\cdot\prod_{k=1}^ia_k+A\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{i}a_k\; \cdot \;\left (\sum_{k=1}^{i}a_k+B-n\right)+n=0$$
but here I am stuck. Any idea?

I have, already, studied the case $i=1$ and $i=2$ (see here [Find $u.v \in \mathbb N$ so that $(u-v)^2-4v$ is a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562414/find-u-v-in-mathbb-n-so-that-u-v2-4v-is-a-perfect-square))

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1$ we can take $a_j=1$ for all $j$ we obtain 
$$
A^2+A(1+B+n)+n=0,
$$
which we can solve easily with $A=1$ and $B=-2n-2$.
Now do induction on $i$.

Comment: Yes, this can be a very easy case; but what happens if $i=6$ for example?

Comment: Yes, I see. With the new edit it becomes more context.

Comment: Can we find a general solution when $i\geq2$?

Comment: I don't see an easy way for all $i\ge 2$.